# Save params value in before_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Hello I am getting this in my params

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"YmYvS/vPVB9FD7+XvDx0+K8UKHReHLifTmc91xD8pASSNqg9d0b/77NnodxQYhbN806661eSBk9vQwTHib3w/w==", "employee"=>{"profile_attributes"=>{"name"=>"dinshaw",
>   "date_of_joining"=>"8 June, 2015", "date_of_birth"=>"2 June, 2015",
>   "aniversary"=>"3 June, 2015", "last_position"=>"Developer",
>   "passport_no"=>"AK972345", "passport_expiry_date"=>"27 June, 2015",
>   "pan_no"=>"BHJ47"}, "email"=>"draje@adroit-inc.com",
>   "role"=>"SUPER-ADMIN", "department_id"=>"1", "designation_id"=>"1",
>   "is_active"=>"1", "contact_attributes"=>{"phone_no"=>"9856321470",
>   "current_address1"=>"test1dinsh", "current_address2"=>"awwwwwwwww",
>   "country"=>"IN", "city"=>"Indore", "zip"=>"452001",
>   "emergency_contact_person"=>"abhi",
>   "emergency_contact_no"=>"9632145870", "relation"=>"farji"},
>   "permanent_address_attributes"=>{"address1"=>"testbghghgjh",
>   "address2"=>"hdvhdkhfdhnbdfds", "country"=>"IN", "city"=>"Ghaziabad",
>   "zip"=>"12356"}}, "contact"=>{"state_code"=>"MP"},
>   "permanent_address"=>{"state_code"=>"CH"}, "commit"=>"Update
>   Employee", "id"=>"1"}

Now in my employee.rb I have included this code

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :designation
  has_one :profile
  has_one :contact
  has_one :permanent_address
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, :contact, :permanent_address
  before_save :set_state_code

  def set_state_code
    self.contact.state_code = 'AP'
    self.permanent_address.state_code = 'MP'
  end

  def create_association_instance
    self.build_profile unless self.profile
    self.build_contact unless self.contact
    self.build_permanent_address unless self.permanent_address
    self.attachments.build unless self.attachments.present?
  end

end
```

But I want

```
self.contact.state_code = params[:contact][:state_code] && 
self.permanent_address.state_code = params[:permanent_address][:state_code]
```

I am not getting how to fetch it in a model. Please guide me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :contact_state_code, :address_state_code
  before_save :set_state_code

  def set_state_code
    self.contact.update_column(state_code: self.contact_state_code)
    self.permanent_address.update_column(state_code: self.address_state_code)
  end
end
```

and in controller do something like:

```
params[:employee][:contact_state_code] = params[:contact][:state_code]
params[:employee][:address_state_code] = params[:permanent_address][:state_code]
```

Comment: If you won't send anything to model then how that value will be saved through model..?